# Function "Delphi" to "PHP"

Tags: php, delphi, function

I am needing to create a function in PHP that returns the same result from a function in Delphi. In the excerpts function in PHP that are commented with "/ /" are the lines that I could not substitute for that returns the same result.

**Delphi Code:**

```
function Crypt_(Action, Src: String): String;
Label Fim;
var KeyLen : Integer;
  KeyPos : Integer;
  OffSet : Integer;
  Dest, Key : String;
  SrcPos : Integer;
  SrcAsc : Integer;
  TmpSrcAsc : Integer;
  Range : Integer;
begin
  if (Src = '') Then
  begin
    Result:= '';
    Goto Fim;
  end;
  Key :=
'YUQL23KL23DF90WI5E1JAS467NMCXXL6JAOAUWWMCL0AOMM4A4VZYW9KHJUI2347EJHJKDF3424SKL K3LAKDJSL9RTIKJ';
  Dest := '';
  KeyLen := Length(Key);
  KeyPos := 0;
  SrcPos := 0;
  SrcAsc := 0;
  Range := 256;
  if (Action = UpperCase('C')) then
  begin
    Randomize;
    OffSet := Random(Range);
    Dest := Format('%1.2x',[OffSet]);
    for SrcPos := 1 to Length(Src) do
    begin
      SrcAsc := (Ord(Src[SrcPos]) + OffSet) Mod 255;
      if KeyPos < KeyLen then KeyPos := KeyPos + 1 else KeyPos := 1;
      SrcAsc := SrcAsc Xor Ord(Key[KeyPos]);
      Dest := Dest + Format('%1.2x',[SrcAsc]);
      OffSet := SrcAsc;
    end;
  end
  Else if (Action = UpperCase('D')) then
  begin
    OffSet := StrToInt('$'+ copy(Src,1,2));
    SrcPos := 3;
  repeat
    SrcAsc := StrToInt('$'+ copy(Src,SrcPos,2));
    if (KeyPos < KeyLen) Then KeyPos := KeyPos + 1 else KeyPos := 1;
    TmpSrcAsc := SrcAsc Xor Ord(Key[KeyPos]);
    if TmpSrcAsc <= OffSet then TmpSrcAsc := 255 + TmpSrcAsc - OffSet
    else TmpSrcAsc := TmpSrcAsc - OffSet;
    Dest := Dest + Chr(TmpSrcAsc);
    OffSet := SrcAsc;
    SrcPos := SrcPos + 2;
  until (SrcPos >= Length(Src));
  end;
  Result:= Dest;
  Fim:
end;
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
function Crypt_($Action, $Src) {
  $Key    = 'YUQL23KL23DF90WI5E1JAS467NMCXXL6JAOAUWWMCL0AOMM4A4VZYW9KHJUI2347EJHJKDF3424SKL K3LAKDJSL9RTIKJ';
  $KeyLen = strlen($Key);
  $KeyPos = 0;
  if ($Action == 'C') {
    $OffSet = rand(0,256);
//  Dest := Format('%1.2x',[OffSet]); //I tried to replace the function "sprintf", but the result is null
    $SrcPos = 1;
    while ($SrcPos <= strlen($Src)) {
      $SrcAsc = (ord($Src[$SrcPos]) + $OffSet) % 255;
      if ($KeyPos < $KeyLen) $KeyPos = $KeyPos + 1; else $KeyPos = 1;
      $SrcAsc = $SrcAsc xor ord($Key[$KeyPos]);
//    Dest := Dest + Format('%1.2x',[SrcAsc]); //I tried to replace the function "sprintf", but the result is null
      $OffSet = $SrcAsc;
      $SrcPos = $SrcPos + 1;
    }
  } else {
//  OffSet := StrToInt('$'+ copy(Src,1,2));
    $Dest   = '';
    $SrcPos = 3;
    while ($SrcPos >= strlen($Src)) {
//    SrcAsc := StrToInt('$'+ copy(Src,SrcPos,2));
      if ($KeyPos < $KeyLen) $KeyPos = $KeyPos + 1; else $KeyPos = 1;
      $TmpSrcAsc = $SrcAsc xor ord($Key[$KeyPos]);
      if ($TmpSrcAsc <= $OffSet) $TmpSrcAsc = 255 + $TmpSrcAsc - $OffSet;
      else $TmpSrcAsc = $TmpSrcAsc - $OffSet;
      $Dest = $Dest + chr($TmpSrcAsc);
      $OffSet = $SrcAsc;
      $SrcPos = $SrcPos + 2;
    }
  }
  return $Dest;
}
?>
```

I wonder also if the "xor", "ord" and "chr" PHP would have the same result as Delphi.

Thanks for the attention of everyone!

Comment: `format` -> `sprintf()`.

Comment: Software Security 101: Writing ones own encryption routine is a bad idea. I accept in this case you've got to do it to be compatible with an existing program, but it's really important to understand that this code has absolutely zero percent chance of being secure in any meaningful way. Both PHP and Delphi have perfectly good encryption libraries built into them, which should be compatible if you specify the same algorithm. Is there any reason why you can't use them?

Comment: Not answering your question, but `if (Action = UpperCase('C')) then` is just silly. `UpperCase('C')` is `'C'`. Is that meant to be `if (UpperCase(Action) = 'C') then`, perhaps? If so, perhaps you should change how you perform that comparison in PHP.

Comment: @SDC , just as you mentioned, I need this same function in PHP because it is already in Delphi distributed with my system. Really, PHP and Delphi have their encryptions functions, but most are one-way, and you can not decrypt them. The function base_encode64 PHP is too bad, because when encrypting always gets the same result as opposed to what I'm doing this.

Comment: @hvd , really is a flaw in the code. Thanks for rating!

Comment: @carlos: base64 is **NOT** encryption. it's an encoding format. taking 8bit data and converting to a 6bit format for safe transmission through systems that mangle 8bit data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Delphi

The `Format` function with argument `%x` converts a integer to a string hexadecimal representation; in this case, a byte. For example 168 is *converted* to `'A8'`.

The StrToInt function with a argument starting with `'$'` does the inverse *conversion*, returning 168 from `'$A8'`.

## PHP

In PHP you can achieve the same results by calling the [`dechex`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php) and [`hexdec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php) functions.

Take into account the `hexdec` call doesn't require the `'$'` prefix.

Comment: Friend thanks for the reply, helped a lot. Now another question that is puzzling me. In this same function have a stretch with "xor", but in PHP always gives a different result. Delphi Code: <code>SrcAsc := SrcAsc Xor Ord(Key[KeyPos]);</code> PHP Code: <code>$SrcAsc = $SrcAsc xor ord($Key[$KeyPos-1]);</code>

Comment: @carlos What's the input?, what you get? what you expect to get?. It looks like a no-question, or maybe a different one.

Comment: @carlos por cierto, sería bueno poder hablar en español, no? :D

Comment: Las líneas correspondientes al "Formato" funcionaba perfecto, ahora esta línea está volviendo resultado diferente.<br/>
Delphi:<br/>
<code>
  SrcAsc := (Ord(Src[SrcPos]) + OffSet) Mod 255; //el valor recibido: 54<br/>
  SrcAsc := SrcAsc Xor Ord(Key[KeyPos]); //el valor recibido: 111 (A partir de PHP también deben recibir el mismo valor)
</code>
PHP:<br/>
<code>
  $SrcAsc = (ord($Src[$SrcPos]) + $OffSet) % 255; //el valor recibido: 54<br/>
  $SrcAsc = $SrcAsc xor ord($Key[$KeyPos]); //valor sigue siendo el mismo: 54, cuando debería ser 111)
</code>

Comment: ahora logró ser devuelto el mismo resultado. Es que he tenido que sustituir por el xor ^. Así funcionó perfectamente. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Enhorabuena y bienvenido a StackOverflow ;)